# How to print the stdout of a external program in a text area using flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

i have a call for a external program but i want to put the output in a text area using ajax and html. the only return that i get it was a last line of stdout.

```
result = subprocess.Popen(command_analysis, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
            while True:

                output_stdout = result.stdout.readline().decode().strip()

                if output_stdout == '' and result.poll() is not None:
                    break
            
                if output_stdout:
                    outreports = f'{self.OUTPUT}{self.name}_report.html
                    data = [output_stdout, outreports]

       return data
```

This data will be for js, and I know, the output_stdout var is overwriting its own value, but how can I do that?

```
  .
  .
  .
    data = {
          'stdout': result[0],
          'report': url_for("static", filename=result[1])
       }
    
       return jsonify(data)
```

> ajax

```
function executeAnalysis(dados){

   $.ajax({
         //async: true,
          url: '/analysis',
          data: dados,
          success: function (ret) {
            console.log(ret)
           console.log(ret.stdout)
           fitList(ret.report);
           $('.stdout').value += ret.stdout;
                
        },

           error: function(error) {
               console.log('Erro:', error);
           }

          });          
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a string variable before starting the loop and add each line to this variable by concatenating.

```
    result = subprocess.Popen(command_analysis, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    output = ""
    while True:

        output_stdout = result.stdout.readline().decode().strip()
        output += output_stdout + "\n"

        if output_stdout == '' and result.poll() is not None:
            break

        if output_stdout:
            outreports = 'report.html'
            data = [output, outreports]

    return data
```

Comment: thx for the answer. But i need that the output is in real time, while the external program is processing send the output in stdout for front end. the output above is all stdout print in the end.

Comment: That wasn't on the question.

Comment: and, did u can help me?